# Hibernate does not restore current session

Tags: 18.04, power-management, hibernate, macbook

When I call `pm-hibernate` my Laptop actually turns off (also when running low on battery) without restoring the current session. Whats arkward is that my screen turns off for a sec, then turns back on for a sec (without taking any input) and then finally turns off. When I use `pm-suspend-hybrid` it is also doing that, but it wakes up back from suspend.

I use a MacBook Pro Late 12, Ubuntu 18.04, i3wm and I have configured 12 Gb of swap (thats 1.5x my RAM size). Any help appreciated, because I couldn't find any related problems online.

Edit: This does not seem to be a Ubuntu-related problem, because I just installed Manjaro on my machine and run into the same issue when trying to hibernate.

Comment: what does `sudo systemctl hibernate` ?

Comment: Ubuntu does not support hibernate on all hardware. It is possible it won't work in yours. By the way, hibernate should turn your machine off completely, but when you power it on, it should come back up in the state you left it. That is, if you had Firefox open to AOL.com, at power on, you should see the same page.

Comment: I agree about the awkwardness part, but isn't the point of hibernation to turn your machine off?  When the screen flickers back on, your machine is in the process of writing to the swap file for hibernation purposes (at least that's what mine is doing_

Comment: @cmak.fr It does the same as `sudo pm-hibernate`.
Yes what I mean is, that I cannot restore my open session after powering back on.